# Usage data from list items (Number of downloads, number of likes)

Tags: web-analytics, metrics

I have a list that allows people to add items and attachments. Is there a way to track usage metrics such as number of downloads or most "liked" (there is a like column in the sharepoint list)?

```
List items
    Title | Open Menu | Open Menu | Description | Tool Category|   Release Notes | Number of Likes
```

Is there a way to do this? Can someone point me to some documentation?

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Check below links if those help:

http://www.nullskull.com/a/1398/sharepoint-list-usage-and-statistics.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/736a2ed1-c370-4189-af6a-fdeeeb6150ef/sharepoint-how-to-check-download-count-for-any-list-items

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457495/does-sharepoint-track-document-downloads

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397403(v=office.12).aspx#MOSS2007ItemLevelAudit_AuditingwithSharePointServer2007

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for reference. See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer for general guidelines